# Tableview data won't print using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to get my saved array in NSUserDefaults and add it to my tableview... When I run `print(notifications[indexPath.row])`my array (notifications) contents get printed. However when I go to add these contents to my tableview, nothing shows up. I'm assuming that although the array gets saved and retrieved via NSUserDefaults, it may not be able to convert the array contents to a string I can add to my tableview. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is some extra code that may be useful:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = notificationsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("notificationsCell") as! NotificationsTableViewCell
    //Set notificationsLabel of cells
    print(notifications[indexPath.row])
    cell.notificationsLabel.text = notifications[indexPath.row] as? String
    //Set datesLabel of cells
    cell.datesLabel.text = dates[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your Array?

Comment: Can you show how did you store an array into `NSUserDefaults`? And make sure if your `notificationsLabel` was initialized and added as a subview to the `cell`.

Comment: Aaron, the data type of my array was not specified so it is AnyObject. However, I am placing string objects into it.

Comment: Shamsiddin, I stored data into `NsUserDefaults` via `userDefaults.setObject(notifications, forKey: "notificationsKey")` and then ran `userDefaults.synchronize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: I had to specify that the array would only be composed of `String`. To do this I initialized the array via `var notifications = [NSString]()`. Then I could use the `append` command to edit that array. Finally, to add the saved content into the array I ran, `notifications = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("notificationsKey") as! [NSString]`.